# invoking market:// link in 4.1.2

Tags: android, webview, android-webview, android-4.2-jelly-bean

We embed a WebView Widget in android app to display some links to other apps, using the [market:// style link](http://developer.android.com/distribute/googleplay/promote/linking.html#OpeningDetails)

It works fine, until a nexus 7 with android 4.1.2, the chrome browser displays page saying the `market://` link can not be opened.

What can we do? How to fix it? TIA.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Register your "market://" scheme using [Intent](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html)